# Initialize an array's pointed address on creation in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization, misra

being a relative newbie in the automotive embedded development, I am currently facing a problem with a pointer which I need to initialize to a given address and who is later used to browse through the ROM of the microcontroller.

As my code must be MISRA-C 2004 compliant, I’d like to initialize this pointer on declaration without allocating new memory, which wouldn’t be used anyway, but, in order to avoid the “Don’t use pointer arithmetic” MISRA-error, I need it to be declared as an array.

Let me show you my current code for clarification:

```
static uint8* MemoryCursor_p = FIRST_ADDRESS_POINTED_BY_CURSOR;
/* Some cool stuff happens here*/
MemoryCursor_p = &( MemoryCursor_p [1]); /* Moving the cursor one byte forward in memory*/
```

This causes the MISRA check to trigger an error, as MemoryCursor_p is not defined as an array, but as a pointer. But if I declare it as an array, I am requested to define the pointed values, but I’d like to set the pointed address on declaration instead.

Of course, if I just try:

```
MemoryCursor_p += 1ul;
```

I am getting scolded by MISRA for using pointer arithmetic.

I’d like to avoid committing MISRA violations. Could someone please tell me how to proceed?

Just as an indication about these bits of code: this is part of the implementation of a simple CRC16 algorithm that does a checksum over some memory.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't you declare `const` variable to hold pointer to first address, and use separate integer index variable for position calculation? That way you wouldn't need to take address of array element.

Comment: I use variables defined by the IDE (IAR) which are two uint8 variables, corresponding to the beginning and the end of the memory section. Wouldn’t I need to call it somehow like this then: (&MemoryRangeStart)[i] ? This looks a bit pythonish, but, actually, yes, I could have, had I thought about it earlier. Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: I was thinking of skipping address operator completely, something like `int currentValue = MemoryRangeStart[i];`.

Comment: This means that I still need the iterator variable, `i`, which would be an uint32. (but without the hassle of the pointer definition) Also, MemoryRangeStart is defined as an uint8 by the IDE/linker/whatever-part-of-IAR-that-defines-it, so this code snippet would be `int currentValue = (&MemoryRangeStart)[i]`. Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: Oh, it's linker created symbol. In that case the syntax makes sense. I thought that `MemoryRangeStart` would be *pointer* containing address of memory start `uin8_t * const MemoryRangeStart = some_hard_coded_address;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never blindly follow MISRA, let alone blindly follow your static analyser warnings.

The mentioned rule 17.4 in MISRA-C:2004 didn't make any sense. It was rather a misguided attempt to prevent using `*(x + i)` instead of the clearer `x[i]`. But the rationale about out-of-bounds errors provided in the rule didn't make any sense and nobody could argue about why the `*(x + i)` form was less safe (apart from being less readable).

This rule has therefore been replaced in MISRA-C:2012. So the correct approach, in my opinion, is to create a company-wide deviation from the rule. Block all warnings related to 17.4.

In any case, you should not attempt to dodge the rule by using some fishy, obfuscated syntax. `MemoryCursor_p++` is correct and the clearest form, use that. Alternatively, use a counter variable `i` and access array item number `i`. Either form is fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. Do you have any reference I could show my superior about this? I did find your message (about 8 years ago) on the MISRA forum, but I'd like to find something that looks more official.

Comment: From the non-public 2012 draft: "Downgraded to Advisory. Relaxation allows ++ and -- on pointers." It might be best just to refer to the new rule in MISRA-C:2012, which is 18.4.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. :) I will try to find out if someone has any MISRA-C:2012 available in the company.

Comment: @Domack It is fairly cheap to buy the pdf from MISRA, just £10. It's fortunately not an ISO standard :)

Answer (score 0):

@Domack - there is a whole section at the front of the MISRA-C:2004 book on Deviations... and a whole book (MISRA C Compliance) now available which is equally applicable if you so wish!  I agree with Lundin, that your best option is to raise a deviation, citing the changes in 2012